# How is ServiceStack support on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, servicestack

I would like to know how well ServiceStack supports client consumption and deserialization into objects on Xamarin for both iOS and Android as the official ServiceStack website does not mention this.

Answer (score 3):

ServiceStack's released [PCL client Libraries support in v4.06](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.0.06) which include support for both iOS and Android Xamarin platforms.

The [Hello repository](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) shows examples of using the libraries in all supported client platforms.

The PCL client libraries are maintained in the [ServiceStack.Client](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client) NuGet package, e.g:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Client
```